# Recently upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10 and now sceen keeps flikering on and off

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade, live-cd

I recently installed 12.04 on my desktop and upgraded to 12.10.

Since then the screen constantly goes blank every 5-8 seconds. It never did this in 12.04. I have the same issues when I have tried to install 12.10 from a live CD.

Answer (score 1):

There is a high probability for this being a driver-related issue.

If you are using the proprietary driver try to upgrade or if this does not help uninstall it.

If you are not, try installing the proprietary driver using:

```
jockey-gtk
```